# Como capturar uma exceção de uma função que esta dentro de um try catch?

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse método assíncrono:

```
async printForNetwork( device ) {
    try {
        const options = {encoding: "860"};
        const printer = new Printer(device, options);

        device.open( err => {
            if (err)
                return err; // preciso lançar a exception desse erro

            printer.align('CT');
            printer.size(1, 2);
            printer.text('Teste');
            printer.close();
        });

    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Preciso lancar uma exceção caso o atributo `err` em `device.open` para tratá-la no `catch`.

mas se eu fizer um `throw` dentro de `device.open` a exceção nao esta sendo capturada.

Comment: Rafael, você não pode fazer o throw e tratar a exceção ao consumir o método, consumindo com then/catch?

Comment: Esse `try catch` não tem sentido, se você apenas vai lanças a exceção, sem nenhum tratamento, não precisa dele

Answer (score 3):

Talvez isso resolva o seu problema:

```
async function printForNetwork( device ) {
try {
    // ...

    await Promise.resolve(device.open( err => {
        if (err) 
          throw err;

        // ...
    }));

} catch (e) {
    throw e;
}
```

}